# How's the formula mass of a molecule calculated? Is it the mass in it's empricial formula or molecular formula?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, molecules, covalent-compounds, chemical-formula

Like glucose, butane and benzene. How would you calculate their formula mass? Would you calculate it as the mass of their empricial formula or their molecular formula (basically same as molecular mass)

I've seen some people say it's the mass of the molecular formula, while others say it's the mass of the empirical formula.

Answer (score 1):

Benzene is $\ce{C6H6}$. Its formula mass is the molecular mass. It is $6·12 + 6·1 = 78$. Its unit is g/mol, or u = atomic mass unit. The same calculation is made for glucose and butane.

Comment: Thanks! So we I'm asked about the formula mass of any molecule, I write it's molecular formula mass instead of its empirical formula mass?

Comment: All these words are synonymous. Formula mass or molecular formula mass or empirical formula mass.

Comment: How are empirical formula mass and molecular formula mass synonyms?

Glucose, butane, and benzene each have a different molecular formula and empirical formula. So they have different values, right?

Like glucose has a molecular mass of 180 (C₆H₁₂O₆), but empirical formula mass of 30 (CH₂O)

Comment: OK. Sorry ! I forgot that empirical formula may be smaller than molecular formula, like $\ce{CH2O}$ for glucose.